# How to calculate $\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^a x \cos^b x \,\mathrm{d} x$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^a x \cos^b x \,\mathrm{d} x = \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1+a}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1+b}{2}\right)}{2 \Gamma\left(1 + \frac{a + b}{2}\right)} \quad\quad\text{for } a, b > -1$$
according to Mathematica. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_trigonometric_functions#Integrands_involving_both_sine_and_cosine) also lists a recursive expression for the indefinite integral when $a, b > 0$. My question is how to derive the explicit formula given by Mathematica (preferably without using esoteric special functions, but complex analysis is fine).

Comment: After a suitable change of variable, LHS can be written as the [beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function). Then use the relationship between gamma function and beta function. I don't know if there is a direct way to prove this.

Comment: @grand_chat I don't think that this question is a duplicate of the one you indicate, as that question assumes that $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$, which significantly simplifies matters.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Yeah, I realized that as I looked more closely. How does one revoke a vote to close?

Comment: Click on the "close (1)" link.  Near the bottom, there is a button to retract your vote. @grand_chat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay first of all we make the substitution $t=\sin^2x$. Thus the integral becomes
$$\frac12\int_0^1t^{\frac{a-1}2}(1-t)^{\frac{b-1}2}\mathrm dt=\frac12\int_0^1t^{\frac{a+1}2-1}(1-t)^{\frac{b+1}2-1}\mathrm dt$$
Then we recall the definition of the Beta function:
$$B(x,y)=\int_0^1t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1}\mathrm dt=\frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}$$
So we have our integral at
$$\frac{\Gamma(\frac{a+1}2)\Gamma(\frac{b+1}2)}{2\Gamma(\frac{a+b}2+1)}$$