# How to solve integral of $\int_{0}^{π/2} \sin^n(θ)\,d\theta$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How would one solve the following? I've tried reduction method, integration by parts, etc. to no avail. 
$$\int_{0}^{π/2} \sin^n(θ),d\theta $$
Thanks.

Comment: Tell us what you get with the reduction method.

Comment: I think this is called a Wallis integral?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate $\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^a x \cos^b x \,\mathrm{d} x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3034225/how-to-calculate-int-0-pi-2-sina-x-cosb-x-mathrmd-x)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove $(n + 1)I(n) = (n + 2)I(n + 2)$ by integration by parts.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1047772/prove-n-1in-n-2in-2-by-integration-by-parts)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By substitution $x=\sin^2\theta$ you can get Euler Beta integral. For any $n>-1$ (not necessarily integer) we have $$\int_0^{\frac\pi 2} \sin^n\theta d\theta = \frac12 \int_0^1 t^{\frac{n-1}{2}}(1-t)^{-\frac12} dt=\frac{\Gamma(\frac{n+1}{2})\Gamma(\frac12)}{2\Gamma(\frac{n}{2}+1)} = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma(\frac{n+1}{2})}{2\Gamma(\frac{n}{2}+1)} $$

Another, more fundamental method may be integrating by parts to get a recursion. We have, for $n>1$:
\begin{align} I_n = \int_0^{\frac\pi 2} \sin^n\theta d\theta &= \int_0^{\frac\pi 2} \sin^{n-1}\theta\sin\theta d\theta = \\ &=(-\sin^{n-1}\theta\cos\theta)|_{\theta=0}^{\theta=\frac\pi 2}+\int_0^{\frac\pi 2}(n-1)\sin^{n-2}\theta\cos^2\theta d\theta = \\ &=(n-1)\int_0^{\frac\pi 2}\sin^{n-2}\theta(1-\sin^2\theta) d\theta =\\&= (n-1) (I_{n-2} - I_n)\end{align}
that is 
$$ I_n = \frac{n-1}{n}I_{n-2}$$
By calculating $I_0$ and $I_1$ directly, and solving the recursion, you can get $I_n$ for any $n\in\mathbb N$.

Answer (score 0):

(I think I got it right!).  The integral $I_n$ has two cases, $n$ odd and even.

For odd $n=2m+1$: 
\begin{split}
I_{2m+1}&=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (1-\cos^2(x))^m \sin(x)dx\\
&=\int_0^1(1-u^2)^mdu\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{m}{k}(-1)^ku^{2k} \nonumber \\
&=\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{m}{k}\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}.
\end{split}

For even $n$: $$I_n=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i})^n=\frac{1}{(2i)^n}\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}e^{(n-2k)ix}dx$$
Looking at all the terms in the sum, except $k=\frac{n}{2}$, they pair up to form $\sin((n-2k)x)$ which integrates to $0$.
The term with $k=\frac{n}{2}$ is $=\binom{n}{\frac{n}{2}}\frac{1}{2^n}$ so the integral is $\binom{n}{\frac{n}{2}}\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}$