# Definite Integral Direct Formula

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

For some of my physics questions I need to evaluate
$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^n\theta\,d\theta$ and 
$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^n\theta \,d\theta$

I know the direct formula for $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^n\theta \,d\theta\;$ which is $(\frac{n-1}{n}*\frac{n-3}{n-3}*......\frac{1}{2})*\frac{\pi}{2}$
My question is what should I do if n is odd
and
What is the similar formula for $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^n\theta\, d\theta$ ?

and some light on how these formulas can be found in internet like 'name of the topic'. Because, all I am finding are how these can be done by integration by parts which I don't want.

Comment: Changing $\theta$ to $\frac {\pi} 2-\theta$ changes one of your integrals to the other.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3276574/how-to-solve-integral-of-int-0%cf%80-2-sinn%ce%b8-d-theta/3276609#3276609

Comment: You can linearise $\cos ^n\theta$ with the complex exponential and the binomial formula.

Answer (score 0):

For the second of your three questions: To obtain the formula for the cosine, note that $$\cos \phi =\sin (π/2-\phi).$$

For your third question, I recall seeing a derivation of these formulae in Todhunter's *Treatise on the Integral Calculus.*

For your first question, note that if $n=2m+1,$ then $\sin ^{2m+1}\phi=\sin^{2m}\phi\sin\phi,$ which can be done by parts.